# C system call msgsnd(): invalid argument error on certain compiler versions

Tags: c, gcc, version, system-calls

Okay so I am working on a college project so sorry for the silly question.

My task is to push a string through a message queue, fork a child process and receive the message then send a response back to the parent process via the same message queue, doing all this in a loop.

I have the code written at home, and it works just fine, but part of the assignment is to make it work on a college server, and that is something I'm having problems with.

**Here's the relevant parts of my code:**

Parent process:

```c
void fel2()
{   
    int messq, status;
    key_t key = ftok("key", 1);
    messq = msgget( key, 0600 | IPC_CREAT ); 

    OpBike * ob_first = NULL;
    ob_first = ob_read_in(ob_first);
    char confirm_string[64];

    while (exists_busy_bike(ob_first))
    {
        sleep(5);
        ob_first = NULL;
        ob_first = ob_read_in(ob_first);

        int busy_bikes = count_busy_bikes(ob_first);
        ob_first = NULL;

        srand(time(NULL));
        int bret = (rand() % busy_bikes);

        ob_first = ob_read_in(ob_first);
        ob_first = ob_read_in(ob_first);

        int ret_bike_id = get_bikeid_by_jumps(ob_first, bret);

        char ret_bike_id_char[64];
        snprintf(ret_bike_id_char, 64, "%d", ret_bike_id);

        send(messq, ret_bike_id_char);
        fel2_child(messq, key);
        ob_first = NULL;

        wait(NULL);

        strcpy(confirm_string, recv(messq));

        ob_first = NULL;
        ob_first = ob_read_in(ob_first);
        wait(NULL);
    }


    status = msgctl( messq, IPC_RMID, NULL ); 
    wait(NULL);
    return;


}
```

Child process:

```c
int fel2_child(int messq, key_t key)
{
    pid_t child = fork();

    if (child > 0) // parent process does nothing here
    {
    } 
    else {          // child
        char rbikeid[64];
        strcpy(rbikeid, recv(messq));

        OpBike * ob_first = NULL;
        ob_first = ob_read_in(ob_first);
        OpRent * or_first = NULL;
        or_first = or_read_in(or_first);

        OpBike * bike_ret = get_bike_by_bikeid(ob_first, rbikeid);
        char check[64];
        strcpy(check, bike_ret->bike_id);

        ob_first = NULL;
        ob_first = ob_read_in(ob_first);

        or_add_return(or_first, ob_first, rbikeid);

        ob_first = NULL;
        ob_first = ob_read_in(ob_first);

        OpBike * bike_check = get_bike_by_bikeid(ob_first, rbikeid);
        strcpy(check, bike_check->bike_status);


        send(messq, check);
        exit(0);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Sender and receiver functions:

```c
int send( int messq, char * text ) 
{ 
     struct message me = { 119, "asd" }; 
     int status; 

     strcpy(me.mtext, text);

     // THIS IS WHERE EVERYTHING GOES WRONG
     status = msgsnd( messq, &me, strlen ( me.mtext ) + 1 , IPC_NOWAIT ); 

     if ( status < 0 ) 
          perror("msgsnd"); 
     return 0; 
} 

char * recv( int messq) 
{ 
     struct message me; 
     int status; 
     status = msgrcv(messq, &me, 1024, 119, 0 ); 

     if ( status < 0 ) 
          perror("msgsnd"); 

     char * ret;
     ret = malloc(sizeof( char ) * strlen (me.mtext));
     strcpy(ret, me.mtext);

     return ret;
}
```

Running the above code on my home computer works flawlessly. Running Ubuntu 14.10, my code compiled with gcc 4.9.1. However, it does not work on the school server running SLES 11 SP 1, having compiled the code with gcc 4.3.4.

The problem is that the string I'm trying to send doesn't get sent properly. It arrives to the function, gets copied into the message structure, and then somewhere disappears in the process and the only thing read back is undefined data.

I am kinda out of ideas now. I have tried putting the declaration of the message queue elsewhere (as suggested by my professor), that did not fix the problem. I can't update the compiler on my school's server so that's just what I have to deal with. Have any of you guys experienced weird behaviour of system calls through different compiler versions? Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks for your replies in advance!

**EDIT 2:** The definition of struct message.

```
struct message { 
     long mtype;
     char mtext [ 1024 ]; 
};
```

Comment: Fixed. AFAIK `msgsnd()` is a SystemV thing. I chose this one because I heard it was easier to use than the posix message queue implementation.

Comment: Please show the definition of "struct message".

Comment: OK... please show how it is defined.  Also, you should check the return code of: ftok() and msgget().

Comment: In function "send()" you have this statement "struct message me"    What is the definition for "struct message"... not "struct msgbuf" ??

Comment: @TonyB I have added an edit to show you how the definition. `ftok()` generates a key to create the queue. `msgget()` returns an id associated with the queue.

Comment: @TonyB Added definition of struct message.

Comment: BTW, you do realize that your "send()" and "recv()" functions have the same name as library functions...  perhaps renaming them would be a good idea, if for no other reason than to avoid confusion... (human or otherwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so turns out that my verion of gcc (or the linux kernel or whatever software component I was using) automatically creates the key file at ftok (note that "key" did not exist on my system). The college server however did not. So

```
key_t key = ftok("argv[0]", 1);
```

or

```
key_t key = ftok("filename", 1);
```

does the trick.